# How to align text to right with in itemize environment using LaTex?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I used `Itemize` environment within `enumerate` environment and used following script to put hours on right

```
\small{\hspace{\fill}\makebox[1cm][l]{\faClockO\hspace{0.5em}{#1}}}\hspace{0.5em}
```

But they are not aligned properly.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragment into a complete compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: BTW, you probably should put \small inside the \makebox.  However, I don't seen anything to explain the behavior shown.